# JNDI .Net implemantation

Tags: java, c#, oracle, c#-4.0, jndi

I've a java code which uses JNDI to acess a Directory and get user/password to login inside a samba.
What I need is a way to covnert it to .Net code. However I read this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56724t67(v=vs.80).aspx) and couldn't understand. I've tried to use DirectorySearcher class in many different ways.

There's a small piece of java code:

```
try {
    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JNDI_FACTORY);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, jndiServerURL);

    ic = new InitialContext(env);

    fileSystemProxy = (T3FileSystemProxy) ic.lookup("Credential");
    } 
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Does somebody know how to implement it?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I couldn't implement JNDI because it's an interface for Java. I've had to get the UNC path and to authenticate using network credential.

```
using (new UNCPathAccess(Path.GetDirectoryName(pathPdf), username, string.Empty, password))
{
    Email.Send(subject, body, email, attachments);
}
```